# How to improve my double select query that takes too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

My table has 2 date fields: start and end. I have millions of records with random durations.
For every date covered by my table I want to know the count of records.

I hope there is a different and cleaner way to approach my problem because I've come up with a solution that will take forever to compute, which is:

First create an intermediary table with the dates

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_points;
SELECT DISTINCT start_date AS time_point
INTO time_points
FROM data
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT end_date FROM data
; -- Totals 8.2 million records
```

Then create a request using both tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;
SELECT time_points.time_point, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM data
 WHERE start_date <= time_points.time_point AND end_date >= time_points.time_point
) AS n 
INTO results
FROM time_points
;
```

Now I am waiting. When I run the second query with TOP(10), it takes 30 seconds. So it would take about 6 months to get my results. I would hope I could get them in half a day maybe.

-> Sample data

-> here is a sample of data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_table](
    [start_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [end_date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-08T11:07:24.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-08T11:28:41.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-08T11:09:55.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-08T12:18:21.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-14T12:30:01.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-14T12:38:40.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-19T11:17:46.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-19T12:20:48.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-31T16:34:07.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-31T16:39:14.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-09T07:17:56.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-09T07:35:31.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-14T07:52:21.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-14T07:59:02.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-08T07:27:11.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-08T07:30:01.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-01T08:01:58.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-01T08:06:14.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_table] ([start_date], [end_date]) VALUES (CAST(N'2021-12-16T07:19:46.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-12-16T07:22:46.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

-> Sample result

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_points;
SELECT DISTINCT start_date AS time_point
INTO time_points
FROM data_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT end_date FROM data_table
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;
SELECT time_points.time_point, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM data_table
 WHERE start_date <= time_points.time_point AND end_date >= time_points.time_point
) AS n 
INTO results
FROM time_points
;
SELECT * FROM results
;
```

(only 2 lines of result:)

- time_point n
- 2021-12-08 11:07:24.000   1
- 2021-12-08 11:09:55.000   2

Comment: Removing the `DISTINCT`s will be a start, you are already forcing `DISTINCT` results with the `UNION` so forcing the data engine to do this 3 times will be expensive.

Comment: You say you have "8.2 million" dates; what sort of "dates" are these? That's more than enough rows to represent every hour from `1900-01-01` to `2800-01-01`, or *every minute* since the start of 2008 to today.

Comment: A small data sample and desired results would be most helpful.   I'm assuming when you mentioned "dates", you really mean datetime's

Comment: This almost looks like an [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) problem because you are calculating a `COUNT(*)` for each time_point. So essentially when calculating the results you are querying the data table 8.2 million times?!? Can you post some sample data so we can see what's going on?

Comment: It actually feels like you are looking for a Gaps-and-Islands solution.    Again, sample data and desires results

Comment: I added data and desired results. Investigating rbar and gaps-and-islands.

Comment: I've done this sort of thing (looking for peak concurrent sessions) and indexing helped. If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create. Truncating your datetime values to the nearest minute may also help, a LOT.

Comment: So with your table of 8 million rows, do you expect 8 million rows of results after your query finishes running?

Comment: Yes I 'only' expect 8 million rows as a result.

Comment: I gave up, used the starting points in my analysis and not concurrent stuff. Indexing made 10 records run in 2 seconds instead of 3 but that was not enough. I think I'd have had more luck writing a program on the side to do some looping but I'm moving on for now. Thanks everyone for the time.